# aws presigned URL for SSE-C specific encryption

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 using a customer provided secret key. I followed this tutorial here:
http://java.awsblog.com/post/TxDQ18N7AAB31J/Generating-Amazon-S3-Pre-signed-URLs-with-SSE-C-Part-5-Finale

My code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myKey", "mySecretKey");
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();

try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.createUploadClient()) {
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest genreq = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("bucketName", "test7.pdf", HttpMethod.PUT);
    SecretKey secretKey = generateSecretKey();
    SSECustomerKey sseKey = new SSECustomerKey(secretKey);
    genreq.setSSECustomerKey(sseKey);

    URL puturl = s3.generatePresignedUrl(genreq);

    HttpPut putreq = new HttpPut(URI.create(puturl.toExternalForm()));

    putreq.addHeader(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_KEY, sseKey.getKey());
    putreq.addHeader(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_ALGORITHM, SSEAlgorithm.AES256.getAlgorithm());
    putreq.addHeader(Headers.SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_CUSTOMER_KEY_MD5, sseKey.getMd5());
    putreq.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("filePath")));
    HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(putreq);
    Assert.assertTrue(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

the URL gets generated, and then when I try to consume I am providing the needed headers, but the problem is that the response is 403 Forbidden.

What am I missing?

Comment: `403 Forbidden` is usually accompanied by  a response body with an explanation of the error, in XML... Can you capture that and edit it into the question?

Comment: that is the problem, that there is no further explanation, just forbidden. take a look: `HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [x-amz-request-id: theId, x-amz-id-2: the2ndId, Content-Type: application/xml, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 13:22:27 GMT, Connection: close, Server: AmazonS3] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/xml,Chunked: true]}}`

Comment: Whatever you're using is hiding the response body.  Those are just the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the SSE-Client Specific encryption upload using pre-signed URL to work, you need to enable SigV4 (by default, SigV2 was enabled for me) There are several ways to enable this - system property, bucket policy etc. but for me this worked:

`AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, new ClientConfiguration().withSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType"));`